# Showing that an operator is self adjoint.

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

How would one go about showing that 
$$A= \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1  \\
    1 & 2
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

is self adjoint?
Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3):

Self adjoint means: $A=A^T$. $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: conjugate transpose right? (even though the components are real)

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours You are correct.  In general it is conjugate transpose.  But, for real matrices it's just transpose.